# How to copy a list structure?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, web-services

I want to test some code for inserting items into a list, but I don't want to insert the items into a list that has production data.  So I'd like to make another list that has the same column names and definitions as this production list.  I have Sharepoint Designer access to the site, and I'm also familiar with using Sharepoint Web Services to make changes.  Is there a way to use either of these approaches (or anything else) to make a test copy of a list, structure only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a list template, create a new list based on that template.